Using com.sun classes without --add-opens
I am making a lib that modifies the AST with an annotation handler for parameter injection (src: http://github.com/PhoenixOrigin/DependencyInjector). Right now, all users are required to include
compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.with {
        jvmArgs = [
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
                '--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
        ]
    }
}

in their gradle files. To bypass that, I tried to shade in the required modules with
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.sun.tools.javac','net.phoenix.javac'
}

But this throws an error here about typecasting between com.sun JavacProcessingEnvironment and the net.phoenix shaded one.
Does anyone know a better way to do it / how to use shadowJar properly to allow for typecasting between com.sun and my shaded classes?

I believe this is the solution used by Lombok. You may be able to do something similar. Or you could write a Gradle (and/or Maven) plugin that adds the annotation processor as a dependency and adds the JVM arguments to the compile task.

tysm, i can get that to work later, if you want the answer credit just post it as a answer
